# Why is the timestamp inserted by the function “now()” shown as 1992?

Tags: dolphindb

I write the following scripts, but the timestamp is wrong:

```py
t=table(10:0, `sym`datetime, [SYMBOL,DATETIME]);
insert into t values("abc",now())
t
```

sym datetime

abc 1992.07.14T09:35:43

```py
print select now()
```

([2021.08.09T10:11:24.080])

The shown time is 1921 when I invoke the function “now()” in the insert into clause. But the shown time is 2021 when I call the function “now()” individually. What’s the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of datetime column is `DATETIME`, but the type of the inserted `data(now())` is `TIMESTAMP`. The inconsistent types cause this problem. Please unify the type of them.